# How to select more rows from subquery

Tags: mysql

When I'm trying to run this query:

```
 select * FROM `activity` 
 WHERE user_id = 1
 AND activity_id NOT LIKE (select activity_id from activity where user_id = 1 ORDER BY activity_id DESC LIMIT 8)
```

I get the follow error:

```
 Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

How can I solve this problem? I want to select the activity_id from the table excluding the latest 8 activity_id's for a certain user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOT LIKE is expecting an expression or a value to compare against and not a resultset.
Change NOT LIKE for NOT IN

Try this one:

```
    SELECT * FROM `activity` 
             WHERE user_id = 1 AND activity_id NOT IN (
                     SELECT activity_id FROM activity WHERE user_id = 1 
                                        ORDER BY activity_id DESC LIMIT 8)
```

Comment: NOT IN and LIMIT is not supported in the subquery for mysql version.

Comment: I've made my own select statement... how do I change this to a a delete statement?

    $sql1 = "select t1.*, t2.activity_id as activity_id_2 
       FROM activity t1
       left join (select user_id,activity_id from activity where user_id = '".$row['user_id']."' ORDER BY user_id,activity_id DESC LIMIT 8) t2
       on (t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.activity_id = t2.activity_id)
       where t2.activity_id is null
       and t1.user_id = '".$row['user_id']."'";

Comment: @Stefan . For a delete statement just make your subquery to return the activity_id values that you want to delete and then:  DELETE FROM activity where activity_id NOT IN (your subquery here)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by doing this:

```
                $sql2 = "DELETE t1.*
                        FROM activity t1
                        left join (select activity_id from activity where user_id = '".$row['user_id']."' ORDER BY activity_id DESC LIMIT 8) t2
                        on (t1.activity_id = t2.activity_id)
                        where t2.activity_id is null
                        and t1.user_id = '".$row['user_id']."'";
```